# taking innerHTML of one div and putting it in another

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid, typeerror

I dont normally do a lot in javascript but I created a little javascript function to allow me to click the header of an accordian and then show the matching text for that header in the box next to it.

```
function getTestimonial(x) {
    var e = document.getElementById('slide'+x);
    var b = document.getElementById('testimonials-slider');
    var c = e.innerHTML;
    b.innerHTML=c;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slide1" class="slide">
    <p>Test 1</p> 
</div>
<div id="slide2" class="slide">
    <p>Test 2</p> 
</div>

<div id="testimonials-slider"><p>Test 1</p></div>


<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a onclick="getTestimonial(1);" href="#collapseOne">
    Header 1
    </a>
</div>
<div class="accordion-heading">
    <a onclick="getTestimonial(2);" href="#collapseTwo">
    Header 2
    </a>
</div>
```

It works fine on the first click, but then every time I click a header after that, I get the following error: 'TypeError: e is null'. This suggest that from the second time of clicking, the getElementById is not working, even if I select the same header that worked the first time.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This question is off topic because it can be solved by changing one letter.

Comment: Seriously, how many times have you edited your question already? Answers and comments were pointless so far! Please know what you want to ask so that our help actually does help you.

Comment: well I didn't realise I had made a typo until someone pointed it out. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was rather silly really. I had put the slide divs within the testimonial slider that was being changed so as soon as I replaced the innerHTML, it overwrote my slide divs. I have moved these outside of the div and it works fine now. The above example works fine also if anyone wants to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `div id="slide1"`. The second one should be `"slide2"` no?

Comment: your right, but it wasn't that that was causing the problem. I just tried to simplify it on here and made a typo. I've edited it now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the id is unique in your HTML. I believe it should be slide1, slide2 etc.
Additionally, where is the element with the id 'testimonials-slider'? May be this will solve your problem!